# Is there an efficient way to share structure between golang packages?

Tags: go, structure, package

I have a short program in Go with the following files part of it.
Program directory structure:

```
myprogram/
    main.go
    server.go
    routines.go
    structs.go
```

These different files contain different function. The `structs.go` file contains a list of structure type defined, and used in several files of my program. What I want to do, now is to split my program into package like in this example :

```
main/
    main.go // the main program
server/
    server.go // a package imported in main
routines/
    routines.go // a package imported in main
```

My problem, is that I do not know where to put `structs.go` because it contains structures used in several package, as in the 'main.go' code.

How to share efficiently this `structs.go` file ? Should I include it (via a symlink to the file) in each of the package I defined, i.e `server`and `routines` and also in main ?

My method may be awkward because I'm a beginner in Go, and in programming generally.

Comment: There is no need to separate stuff into it's own package. Ask yourself: What actual benefit results from this split? And now compare to the costs.

Comment: The objective is to re-use some of these packages in others programs than `main`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Don't link files across packages, that's bad practice. For one, the code will be duplicated. For another, identifiers will be duplicated meaning to denote the same entities (e.g. type or function), but they will be distinct. E.g. if linked and `structs.go` would contain a `type Response` definition, you would have 2 distinct types `server.Response` and `routines.Response` giving just more confusion.

One solution would be to put `structs.go` into its own package, e.g. `model`, and all other packages relying on it can import it (e.g. your `main`, `server` and `routines`).

In a theoretical example: if package `A` imports package `B` and `structs.go` would be needed in both, then it could also be added to package `B`. If there would be a package `C` needing only `structs.go`, then again it would be wiser to create its own package `model` (so package `C` doesn't need to import / know about package `B`, only the new `model` package).

Also if noone else will use your package and it is not too complex, it might not worth the hassle to organize it into multiple packages.

Comment: Ok, so you recommend me to create a package of structures ,e.g `model`. 
Thank you for this answer, I hope it's a good practice in Go.

Comment: As far as I know (and been told on IRC), go discourages from creating model packages. See: https://medium.com/@benbjohnson/standard-package-layout-7cdbc8391fc1 and https://rakyll.org/style-packages/ for just two examples

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to define a type in one package only and to use it in other packages this way:

```
package one
type A struct{ B int }
```

Variant 1:

```
package two
. import "one"
var name A
```

Variant 2:

```
package two
import "one"
type A = one.A
var name A
```

I would prefer variant 2.

Answer (score 0):

From golang 1.18 on, you can make use of go.work file to create a workspace.
Note: This will not solve the problem of sharing structs between packages but you can share structs between files in the same package.
In the example below, "ONE" type used to instantiate the whole XPTO module. Any variable of this type will have access to all the methods with the receiver *ONE, no matter the file you are inside the package.

File A
package xpto
type ONE struct {}

File B
package xpto

File C
package xpto

Source: https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/workspaces

Answer (score 0):

Generally try to keep structs close to their use cases, we generally use the following (although its very context dependent so more a guide than a rule):

```
/web/model/...         // API request/response types
/model/...             // DTOs used internally throughout the app
/repo/items/...        // or /repo/entity/... Objects persisted to DB
/service/interfaces.go // to describe the service layer in full, sometimes struct DTOs makes sense there
```

I'd also steer clear of a 'structs.go' file - its usually better to have a struct per file as you can add marshalling and other behaviours more clearly - and name the file to align, e.g.:

```
/web/model/create_order_request.go
/web/model/create_order_response.go
```